# Collecting and Returning Error List in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to gather a list of errors in Django Rest Framework and return them to the frontend without performing any database or media operations. For example, errors during serialization, billing validation (if the user lacks permissions), or if a user tries to create something with a name that already exists. I want all validations to pass and then return this list to the user. I'm interested in potential approaches or if anyone has encountered a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # Your fields goes here OR use class Meta to define the model and fields.

    def validate(self, data):
        errors = {}  

        # Perform your custom validations
        if condition:
            errors['field_name'] = 'Your error message comes here that will show on frontend.'
        # Further logic comes here...
        if errors:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(errors)

        return data
```

you can use a model serializer or a simple serializer as per your requirements.